# Swift: app crashes after deleting a column in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

In Parse I accidentally deleted a column called "likes" that counts the number of a likes a user receives for their blog post. I created the column again with the same name but now when I run my app it crashes and I receive this message "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". It points to my code where its suppose to receive the "likes" in my cellForRowAtIndexPath. I pasted my code below. Is there any way I could fix this issue and stop it from crashing?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BCell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! BlogCell

    if let object : PFObject = self.blogPosts.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as? PFObject {

        cell.author.text = object["blogger"] as? String
        cell.post.text = object["blogPost"] as? String
        let dateUpdated = object.createdAt! as NSDate
        let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

        cell.timer.text =  NSString(format: "%@", dateFormat.stringFromDate(dateUpdated)) as String



        let like = object[("likes")] as! Int
        cell.likeTracker.text = "\(like)"


    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: The `let like = object[("likes")] as! Int` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would inspect what's going on with the `object` if I were you. You clearly aren't getting data that you expected to be there. As a stopgap, you can change `let like = object["likes"] as! Int` to

```
if let like = object["likes"] as? Int {
   cell.likeTracker.text = "\(like)"
}
```

If you do that, you will also want to implement the `prepareForReuse` method in `BlogCell` to set that label's text to `nil` or else you might have some weird cell reuse bugs.

Comment: But why did it crash after I deleted the column?. It was working perfectly before

Comment: My experience with Parse is pretty minimal so I'm not sure. I'd guess either you have a typo in the column name, there's some sort of server-side caching, or potentially Parse didn't like that it had the same name as a previous column. You should investigate what you're getting back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Where you delete a column from uitableview , you need to delete data from data source, and update the delete index or reload the whole table .
Look for if you are missing that step